# Swift_TransportException:Laravel Swift Mail

Tags: php, laravel, email, smtp

I have a Laravel 5 project, and it is having trouble sending mail from our mail server. This mail server is working for another Laravel project with the almost identical setup.

I get the following error:

`(1/1) Swift_TransportException`
`Expected response code 250 but got code "", with message ""`

I have my mail.php file setup as such:

`<?php`
`return [`
`'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),`
`'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),`
`'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),`
`'from' => [`
`'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'no-reply@xtreme.com.au'),`
`'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Xtreme IT'),`
`],`
`'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),`
`'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),`
`'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),`

And the .env file that is overwriting those settings:

`MAIL_DRIVER=smtp`
`MAIL_HOST=mail.ourdomain.com.au`
`MAIL_PORT=25`
`MAIL_USERNAME=username@ourdomain.com.au`
`MAIL_PASSWORD=OURPASSWORD`
`MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls`
`MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=no-reply@clientdomain.com.au`
`MAIL_FROM_NAME="Client"`

Is there an easy way to check that my .env file is being used?

I can't work out why the mail will send on one site but not another.

Answer (score 0):

Answering to the question: "Is there an easy way to check that my .env file is being used?"

You can use the env and config helpers doing:

```
dd(env($var_name), config($var_name));
```

Using it, you'll can see if they're the same.
If not, is possible that config cache is outdated, so you can try:

```
php artisan config:clear
```

and then

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Good look!